# Divisibility criterion of a number by $7$, $11$ or $13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

To paraphase my textbook:

> Use that $1001 = 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$ to prove that if $a= a_n a_{n-1}\dots a_1 a_0$ in base $10$, then, respectively, $7$ or $11$ or $13$ divides $a$ if and only if it divides $a_2 a_1 a_0- a_5 a_4 a_3 +a_8 a_7 a_6- \cdots $.

I'm on the chapter of my textbook in which modular congruences are introduced.

Comment: because  $1000\equiv-1\bmod1001$, $a=a_2a_1a_0+1000 a_5a_4a_3+1000^2 a_8a_7a_6-...\equiv a_2a_1a_0-a_5a_4a_3+a_8a_7a_6-...\bmod1001$ and thus $\bmod7,11,13$

Comment: This should remind you of the divisibility tests for $11$ and $101$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Your equality shows that $1000\equiv -1\mod 7\;(\text{or }11,\;\text{or }13).$

Now writing $a$ in base $1000$ consists in grouping its digits by groups of $3$, starting from the right, namely:
$$a=(a_2a_1a_0)1000^0+(a_5a_4a_3)1000+(a_8a_7a_6)1000^2+\dotsm$$
so that, for instance,
$$a\bmod 7\equiv (a_2a_1a_0)-(a_5a_4a_3)+(a_8a_7a_6)-\dotsm$$

Comment: I think you should remove $1000$ from the last line

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Still another copy-paste accident… Thanks for warning me!

Comment: I definitely should reread what I post! ;o)

Comment: Thanks for the help!